# arrays, sizes not expected value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I can't understand what is happening in my code:

```
 for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in jsonResponse) {


     NSString *days = [dict objectForKey:@"dayOfTheWeek"];

     NSArray *arrayDays = [days componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

     NSLog(@"la var %@ size %lu", days, sizeof(arrayDays));


     for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(arrayDays); i++){

        NSLog(@"el dia %@",[arrayDays objectAtIndex:i]);

     }
}
```

What I get in log:

```
2012-07-02 10:06:57.191 usualBike[1342:f803] var M T W T F size 4
2012-07-02 10:06:57.191 usualBike[1342:f803] day M
2012-07-02 10:06:57.192 usualBike[1342:f803] day T
2012-07-02 10:06:57.192 usualBike[1342:f803] day W
2012-07-02 10:06:57.193 usualBike[1342:f803] day T
2012-07-02 10:06:57.193 usualBike[1342:f803] var S S size 4
2012-07-02 10:06:57.194 usualBike[1342:f803] day S
2012-07-02 10:06:57.194 usualBike[1342:f803] day S
```

And crashes, because position 3 doesn't exist.

Why the size is not changing the second time? it should be 1.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(theArray)` calculates the size of the datatype, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).
`[theArray count]` and `theArray.Count` return the count of objects in the array.

Replace both occurrences of `sizeof(arrayDays)` by `arrayDays.Count`.

Note: You can also loop the array using the following:

```
for (NSString* theValue in arrayDays) {
    NSLog(@"el dia %@",theValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use sizeof. It will return you pointer size which is fix for any pointer type variable like string, dictionary, array etc.

You should count property of NSArray.

Change below line of  code,

```
 NSLog(@"la var %@ size %lu", days, sizeof(arrayDays));
```

with this line:

```
 NSLog(@"la var %@ size %lu", days, arrayDays.count);
```

Do the same in loop statement also.

Answer (score 1):

`Sizeof()` will only work for a fixed size array .use   `[arrayDays count]`